# Convert DataFrame column from string to datetime for format "January 1, 2001 Monday"

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime-format

I am trying to convert a dataframe column "**date**" from `string` to `datetime`. I have this format: "**January 1, 2001 Monday**".

I tried to use the following:

```
from dateutil import parser
for index,v in df['date'].items():
   df['date'][index] = parser.parse(df['date'][index])
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot set non-string value '2001-01-01 00:00:00' into a StringArray.
```

I checked the datatype of the column "**date**" and it tells me `string` type.

This is the snippet of the dataframe:

[image]

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre]. Instead of describing the actual data, **show** us data (i.e., code that creates a small, example `DataFrame`) that **demonstrates the problem**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you try this instead of `dateutils`, `pandas` offer much simpler tools such as `pd.to_datetime` function:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%B %d, %Y %A')
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to skip the rows that are NaN?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the format for the `datetime` object in order it to be parsed correctly. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) helps with this:

- `%A` is for Weekday as locale’s full name, e.g., Monday
- `%B` is for Month as locale’s full name, e.g., January
- `%d` is for Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.
- `%Y` is for Year with century as a decimal number, e.g., 2021.

Combining all of them we have the following function:

```py
from datetime import datetime

def mdy_to_ymd(d):
    return datetime.strptime(d, '%B %d, %Y %A').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    
print(mdy_to_ymd('January 1, 2021 Monday'))


> 2021-01-01
```

One more thing is for your case, `.apply()` will work faster, thus the code is:

```py
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: mdy_to_ymd)
```

Feel free to add Hour-Minute-Second if needed.

Comment: user @sdkayb also provides an answer. It works exactly like mine.